# Moving to Aptana, need to add existing working as a project

Tags: eclipse, svn, aptana, workspace

I have been using Coda since it's been released on Mac OS and would like to move to Aptana.

The project is nicely set up in Aptana with the root folder set to the working copy.

**Is there a way to ask Aptana to use SVN with this working copy?**

It would be good to avoid checking out again the whole folder.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never used Aptana but in Eclipse (which Aptana is based on) when you have a working copy of a project checked out from svn in a different way than via IDE (like by command line svn) and you:

- right click on the project
- choose *Team->Share Project*

IDE auto detects that the project is a working copy and you do not need to check out whole folder again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to be just the right thing. It didn't work in my case for some reason, the Subclipse plugin noticed the .svn folders but said it needs to remove then, and that a Subversion metadata folder is required to connect automatically.